# Leaflet LitElement "L is not defined" in Plugin

Tags: leaflet, lit-element, leaflet.markercluster

I am using Leaflet in a LitElelement webcomponent.
Leaflet itself works great.

But when I want to include a plugin I get the error *"L is not defined"* from the plugin.
I installed Leaflet and the plugin (markercluster) via npm and use it in a Typescript module.

So far I include it like this:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.esm.js';
import 'leaflet.markercluster';
```

And get the following error:

```
MarkerClusterGroup.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined
    at MarkerClusterGroup.js:5
    at leaflet.markercluster-src.js:10
    at leaflet.markercluster-src.js:11*
```

How do I have to include plugins to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet plugins [doesn't support ESM/ES6 imports well](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/874).

According to [this comment](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/874#issuecomment-750647042) you should be able to get `leaflet.markercluster`  to work.

```js
import { Map, Marker,  } from "leaflet";
import { MarkerClusterGroup } from "leaflet.markercluster/src";

...
let mcluster = new MarkerClusterGroup({ chunkedLoading: true });
```

Comment: To be more precise, Leaflet _plugins_ expect `L` (from Leaflet) to be available globally. Leaflet alone has no issue being used as a module.

Comment: Hi abraham and ghybs,

thanks for your answer. Do you have an idea how I could include leaflet in a module so that plugins also work?

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I have tried the import this way before, but unfortunately I get the same error message "L is not defined".